# A like/unlike system using MySQL and PDO

Tags: php, sql, mysql, pdo

I have created a Like/Unlike system. The user clicks one to indicate a "like", and clicks again to "unlike" it. Currently I do that like this:

```
try {                                             -- like
    $stm1 = $db_conn->prepare("INSERT into votes (post_id, user_id) VALUES (?, ?)");
    $stm1->execute(array($post_id, $_SESSION['id']));

} catch(PDOException $e){
    if ((int) $e->getCode() === 23000) {          -- unlike
        $stm2 = $db_conn->prepare("DELETE FROM votes WHERE post_id = ? AND user_id = ?");
        $stm2->execute(array($post_id, $_SESSION['id']));

    } else {
        $error = true;
    }
}
```

**Note:** `$e->getCode() === 23000` means row is duplicate. because there is a **unique** index on `post_id` and `user_id` columns.

Well my code works as well. Just when a professional programmer see it, he says: your algorithm is wrong and you shouldn't delete something when insert fails *(on duplicate)*.

Well, should I change my current code? What's wrong with it? Trust me it works perfectly :) ..!

Comment: Why don't you ask the guy who told you it's bad what he meant exactly?

Comment: My only thought is that *unliking* something isn't exceptional - it's an intended feature of the application. Treating it as an exception means treating it like an error, which it isn't.

Comment: @Mast I did .. but he just says *"deleting on error isn't a good idea"* ..! that's what I cannot understand.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but are you absolutely sure this works? I'm no PHP expert, but this looks like an odd way of database management.

Comment: @Mast Yes I'm pretty sure it works .. I tested it several times.

Comment: Ask him again. And no, deleting on error is never a good idea. The whole concept is wrong. Don't use error handling as a glorified conditional.

Comment: So essentially, if it is present in your database, that means it's a "Like", and if it's not present, there is no like? I suppose that's why you have the feature that removes it if it already is there? So if it was liked already, clicking will unlike it?

Comment: @SimonForsberg Yes .. it it was liked already, clicking will unlike it.

Comment: If you wanted to get out of the using an exception to handle the condition. You could try doing it in reverse. Delete first, and if the number of affected rows is 0, then do an insert. However same end result.

Comment: @bumperbox clever `:-)`

Answer (score 4):

This design is a consequence of a poorly designed API. It looks like the client will hit one URL that will cause the like/unlike state to be toggled. But what if the user has multiple tabs open on the same page, then clicks "like" on each one? The user might believe that they are reiterating the "like", when in fact they are undoing it.

My advice is not to toggle the state on the server side. Offer "like" and "unlike" as two separate calls. The client should be responsible for deciding which API to call, based on the client-side state.

Comment: Yes exactly cliend hit one URL for both like and unlike state. However I don't understand your point of multiple tabs. Anyway +1

Answer (score 3):

There are (at least) two different approaches that are better than your current approach.

One option is to run a `SELECT` query first to check whether it exists or not. If it exists, run `DELETE`. If it doesn't exist, run `INSERT`. Personally I wouldn't prefer this solution as it is slower than necessary and, if implemented correctly, would require more table locking. Consider the case of two scripts running simultaneously, here's what *could* happen:

- Script 1 queries database and finds that nothing exists yet
- Script 2 queries database and finds that nothing exists yet
- Script 1 inserts into database
- Script 2 inserts into database

Now both scripts will insert into database, which will cause a duplicate on the second one.

---

Another option is to use an additional column in your database that specifies whether or not it is a like. So instead of running `DELETE` on your existing row, you can just run `UPDATE` and set the flag to false (to say "don't count this"). Using this option allows you to run an [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) statement that can handle both cases.

I agree that catching an exception and deleting the row in that case is not a good way to handle. You shouldn't use `try ... catch` as normal program flow. Exceptions are meant to be *exceptions*, not normal behavior.

Comment: Your first approach is acceptable .. thx +1

Comment: Your `INSERT … ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` is a fine solution. However, the `SELECT` with a possible `DELETE` is bad advice: it creates all kinds of race conditions.

Comment: @200_success Agreed, I thought about that as well. I edited.

Answer (score 1):

It does look a little dirty depending on errors for normal operations. This will bloat error logs. I think it would be more proper to write a stored procedure that first SELECTs whether the record exists, then dependent on result inserts or deletes the record.

Answer (score 1):

I would not recommend to implement any application logic relying on Exceptions created through external sources.

Imagine someone drops the unique index in your database (through fault or purpose). Your application would still be working, but it will be possible to "like" a post an unlimited amount of times. Because the Exception will never be thrown.

You surely will notice it, but until then your table `votes` will be in an inconsistent state.

An option would be to include a `score` column inside votes table. This way you could follow these step.

1. Insert entry of score 1/0 into table for `post_id`,`user_id` on first like/unlike.
   or
2. Set score to 1/0 for `post_id`,`user_id` on successive like/unlike's.

Comment: Exactly. `INSERT into votes (post_id, user_id, score) VALUES (?, ?, 1) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE score=1-score`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do this in a Not style so you do to the following:

1.Get the answer of the current user whether like or unlike.

2.Make an inverting to this answer.

3.then make the modify operation with the new answer

-Note that you have to add a field in your table which is the value that would be 0 or 1 according to like or unlike.